# Incorrect link to theorem with only enumerate/itemize inside

Tags: hyperref, enumerate, amsthm

I have a bug with command `autoref`/`ref` from `hyperref` package. If there is nothing except enumerate/itemize link to theorem doesn't work: it goes to the beginning of document instead of theorem. How can I fix this?

There is also strange behavior: all works correctly if you don't import `amsthm` package.

Minimal example: link to `t-2` works properly, while `t-1` doesn't. If you remove `\usepackage{amdthm}` all works correctly

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}
    \label{t-1}
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item a
        \item b
    \end{enumerate}
\end{theorem}


\begin{theorem}
    \label{t-2} Text
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item a
        \item b
    \end{enumerate}
\end{theorem}

Reference to \ref{t-1}

Reference to \ref{t-2}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Use `\phantomsection\label{t-1}`.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer `phantomsection` fixed incorrect link, but `autoref` reference now gives incorrect name (section name instead of theorem). How to make it work too?

Comment: Use `\csname hyper@refstepcounter\endcsname{theorem}\label{t-1}`. But only in such cases.  In the other theorem this would lead to a duplicated destination.

Comment: Shouldn't hyperref be loaded last?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found `cleveref` package. It fixed problem without extra code. I think, it's optimal solution for me